# Sorting an array passed to a function as parameter

Tags: arrays, bash, function, sorting

I wanted to have some helper function for array sorting, that I would be able
to use whenever I need it. So I did something like this. It works.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# sorts an array given as param
function array_sort {

    declare -a source_array=("${!1}")
    sorted_array=($(for elmnt in "${source_array[@]}"; do echo $elmnt; done | sort))
    echo "${sorted_array[@]}" # wont echo to stdout, because of assignment to a variable
}

# TEST CASE

# orginal array
arr=(c b a 3 2 1)

#assign function call to a variable
sorted=$(array_sort arr[@])

# echo-out the results
echo ${sorted[@]}
```

My question is, is there some better(cleaner) way of doing this, in terms of returning array elements from function (not implementing better sorting algorithm)?

Comment: Seems pretty reasonable.  What is the problem with this?

Comment: No problem at all. Just being curious if it was possible maybe to call that function without $(), like in other languages.

Comment: You should use quotes: `echo "$elmnt"` even though it's a bit useless since your method fails when there are wildcards (`*`) or spaces or newlines or other funny symbols in your array. Just to let you know.

Comment: I tried with spaces and it works, not shure what you mean? `arr=("c a" b "a x" 3 2 1)` gives `1 2 3 a x b c a`, which is good.

Comment: Use `declare -p sorted_array` to see what your array really contains. Also try with `arr=( '*' )` just for fun. Then try with `arr=( '*' )` _and with the quoted `echo`:_ `echo "$elmnt"`.

Comment: you mean I do not have separated elements in return value?

Comment: Yes. Did you also try the wildcard?

Comment: how would I resolve those two cases. element separation and preventing expansion of that `*` ?

Comment: For this you could use an implementation of a sorting algorithm, e.g., the one in my answer. I've also added a partial fix (along your solution using `sort`) that addresses all the issues except the embedded newlines.

Comment: I did [this a while back](https://github.com/kojiromike/bash-sort/) as an algorithms exercise. Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a robust sorting function (i.e., one that will deal with spaces and newlines flawlessly), you may consider implementing a sorting algorithm in Bash: here's a quicksort.

```
quicksort() {
    # sorts the positional elements wrt alphanumerical sort
    # return is in array quicksort_ret
    if (($#==0)); then
        quicksort_ret=()
        return
    fi
    local pivot=$1 greater=() lower=() i
    shift
    for i; do
        if [[ "$i" < "$pivot" ]]; then
            lower+=( "$i" )
        else
            greater+=( "$i" )
        fi
    done
    quicksort "${greater[@]}"
    greater=( "${quicksort_ret[@]}" )
    quicksort "${lower[@]}"
    quicksort_ret+=( "$pivot" "${greater[@]}" )
}


$ quicksort c b a 3 2 1
$ printf '%s\n' "${quicksort_ret[@]}"
1
2
3
a
b
c
```

You can change the ordering test in the line

```
if [[ "$i" < "$pivot" ]]; then
```

by whatever you like. E.g., for numerical only sort, you'd use

```
if ((i<pivot)); then
```

You can even use a variable (e.g., quicksort_order) that will expand to an ordering function. In this case, replace the former line by

```
if $quicksort_order "$i" "$pivot"; then
```

and use with, e.g., if you want alphanumerical sort:

```
order_alnum() { [[ $1 < $2 ]]; }
quicksort_order=order_alnum
```

The `quicksort` function uses the positional parameters for input and the variable `quicksort_ret` for output. It's now trivial to make a wrapper around this function to handle an array name as input.

---

For a method that, like yours, uses `sort` but fixes the issues with wildcards and spaces (but doesn't fix issues with newlines). Uses the builtin `mapfile`, so this is Bash≥4 only. For Bash<4, there are other workarounds (but you shouldn't be using Bash<4 anymore anyways).

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# sorts an array given as param
# return is in array sorted_array
array_sort() {
    mapfile -t sorted_array < <( printf '%s\n' "${!1}" | sort )
}

# TEST CASE 1
echo "Test 1"
# original array
arr=(c b a 3 2 1)
# sort array
array_sort "arr[@]"
# display array
declare -p "sorted_array"

# TEST CASE 2
echo "Test 2"
# original array
arr=( '*' 'a space in this field' )
# sort array
array_sort "arr[@]"
# display array
declare -p "sorted_array"

# TEST CASE 3 (fails)
echo "Test 3"
# original array
arr=( $'there is\na newline\nin this array' )
# sort array
array_sort "arr[@]"
# display array
declare -p "sorted_array"
```

will output:

```
Test 1
declare -a sorted_array='([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="a" [4]="b" [5]="c")'
Test 2
declare -a sorted_array='([0]="*" [1]="a space in this field")'
Test 3
declare -a sorted_array='([0]="a newline" [1]="in this array" [2]="there is")'
```

---

Answering your questions in comment:

> So that way I would have to know the name of that `sorted_array` variable, to use it in my scripts. Can that be avoided?

If you want to give the name of the sorted array, modify `array_sort` as:

```
array_sort() {
    # $1 is the name of array to sort (with the trailing [@])
    # $2 is the name of the returned array (without [@])
    # Note: name of output array can be name of input array
    mapfile -t "$2" < <( printf '%s\n' "${!1}" | sort )
}
```

and use as:

```
$ a=( a g e z j r )
$ array_sort "a[@]" a_sorted
$ declare -p a_sorted
declare -a a_sorted='([0]="a" [1]="e" [2]="g" [3]="j" [4]="r" [5]="z")'
```

If you want to use the `quicksort` function from my first answer, you'd use a wrapper function (sorry about the name)<sup>(*)</sup>:

```
quicksort_gniourf() {
    # $1 is the name of array to sort (with the trailing [@])
    # $2 is the name of the returned array (without [@])
    # Note: name of output array can be name of input array
    # This is a wrapper function around the quicksort function
    quicksort "${!1}"
    local k=0 v
    declare -g "$2=()"
    for v in "${quicksort_ret[@]}"; do
        printf -v "$2[$k]" '%s' "$v"
        ((++k))
    done
}
```

and use as (here I'm using the same array name for input and output):

```
$ a=( a g e z j r )
$ quicksort_gniourf "a[@]" a
$ declare -p a
declare -a a='([0]="a" [1]="e" [2]="g" [3]="j" [4]="r" [5]="z")'
```

> Also, how would you echo out that resulting array, preventing expansion of `*`, with `declare -p` it is ok, however with `printf` or echo it expands on filenames?

To print an array `array` using `echo` without expanding wildcards (observe the quotes):

```
echo "${array[@]}"
```

and using `printf`, one field per line (observe the quotes):

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> As @konsolebox mentions in his comment, `declare -g` appeared in bash 4.2. You can replace this line with `eval "$2=()"` if you like (it's fairly safe at this point since `$2` is supposed to be a variable name anyways).

Comment: So that way I would have to know the name of that sorted_array variable, to use it in my scripts. Can that be avoided? Also, how would you echo out that resulting array, preventing expansion of `*`, with `declare -p` it is ok, however with `printf` or `echo` it expands on filenames?

Comment: Great! Appreciating your time on solving these issues.

Comment: Using `declare -g` would require Bash 4.2 as minimum so you shouldn't use this if you're using Bash that's earlier than it or else unexpected and possibly dangerous behaviour could happen.

Comment: @konsolebox right, added an `eval` (lol) workaround. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Yep `eval` is still the best choice. `declare -g` is a good hack but is still dirty for me. I believe `declare` was never meant for such assignments.

Comment: I cannot understand your quicksort algorithm, I've even put `set -x` to trace it, but still can't catch the logic behind it. ;)

Comment: @branquito: Quicksort is very standard. The main message (allegorically speaking) is _divide and conquer_: we choose the first element of the list and use it as a pivot (that's the `pivot` variable in the function). We then filter the remaining elements into 2 lists: the list `greater` contains all elements greater than `pivot` and the list `lower` contains the other elements. We then (recursively) apply the algorithm to each of these lists, and finally concatenate them to obtain the fully sorted list.

Comment: @branquito: try with a pen and paper. Choose a list of numbers, e.g., 4, 73, 1, -2, 5, 11. First step: choose the pivot 4. Then do the filtering, you'll have two lists: `greater=( 73 5 11 )` and `lower=( 1 -2 )`. Then apply the same to each sublist: for greater you'll choose the pivot 73 and obtain `greater=()` and `lower=( 5 11 )` and so on and so on. (don't know if it's clear, but try it on your own with a pen and paper, trying to follow each line of the code with this example—it's a wonderful exercise). I don't know if I mentioned it already, but do it on your own with pen and paper `:)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I understand the part about lower and greater, but trace shows at the end
few consecutive lines of:

 `quicksort_ret+=( "$pivot" "${greater[@]}" )`

, that part is unclear to me, pretty much `;)`

Anyway I will try later to put this all together on paper, as you said. `;)`

Comment: @branquito: `quicksort_ret+=( "$pivot" "${greater[@]}" )` appends to the array `quicksort_ret` the pivot and the array `greater`.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort an array like this:

```
arr=(c b a 3 2 1)
sarr=( $(sort < <(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}")) )
printf "%s\n" "${sarr[@]}"
1
2
3
a
b
c
```

**EDIT:** To make it into a function:

```
array_sort() {
    declare -a source_array=("${!1}");
    sarr=( $(sort < <(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}")) );
    echo "${sarr[@]}";
}
```

Comment: I know. But that does not involve function call, as I said, wanted to have some kind of utility functions, that I can use whenever I need them.

Comment: Any script can be put into a function. See updated answer for making it into a function.

Comment: Yes of course it can. But you missed completely the point of my question. Question was not about how to sort an array (because as you can see I know how to do that), but instead, is there some better way of calling that function, or returning results from it.

Comment: No, I didn't miss any point while answering this. Intent of my answer was to show you an alternate (and may I dare say better) way to do the same thing you are doing in your function. If you pay little more attention to my answer you will notice how **I am avoiding looping through the array** that you're doing in your code.

Comment: Yes you did. Again, it is not a question about optimizing sorting alghorithm, but instead a question on, how to do a better returning of array elements from function.

Comment: Sorting algorithm is still the same here. This answer is for the question you asked which is this **Is there some better(cleaner) way of doing this?** And I would say, yes my suggested code is better(cleaner) because of reason I stated above.

Comment: Ok I redefined my question. Now it should be clearer.

Comment: Hmm not sure if editing a question like this is fair to folks who spend their time in answering **originally stated problem**. In any case if you're looking for `return` statement in BASH then you're using wrong tool. Writing the result to some medium is the only way you can get a function return some value in BASH.

Comment: if it was a question about sorting then i wouldn't even post anything about function calls, so please give me a break.

Comment: Your question was not just about sorting but sorting an array.

Comment: You finally understood.

Comment: I always did but looks you still didn't understand my solution and adamant on time wasting verbatim.

Comment: Please do not waste more of your time.

Answer (score 0):

Forwarded from [PlayShell](http://sourceforge.net/projects/playshell)'s [array/sort.sh](http://sourceforge.net/p/playshell/code/ci/master/tree/source/array/sort.sh), here's a pure Bash solution that uses Quicksort algorithm.

```
# ---- array.sh ----

# array_copy (avar <src>, avar <dest>) :: boolean
#
# Copies a whole array including index (key) structure.
#
# For a faster method that does not copy key structure, see
# array_get_all().
#
# This function will return true status code even if the source array
# is empty.  It may only return false if other problem occurs like for
# example if source or destination array is not an indexed array
# variable or if the two array variables are not compatible.
# On the other hand, array_get_all() returns false if source array is
# empty.
#
function array_copy {
    local -i __I
    eval "$2=() && for __I in \${!$1[@]}; do $2[__I]=\${$1[__I]}; done"

    # I hope AVAR=() does not reset variable's attributes.  I've been
    # wondering if I should use 'unset AVAR\[*\]' instead.  The latter
    # version probably is a bit slower though since it's a builtin call.
}

# array_reset (avar <array>, [mixed <element_value>, ...])
#
# Clears an array or resets it to optional elements.
#
function array_reset {
    eval "$1=(\"\${@:2}\")"
}

# ---- array/sort.sh ----

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# array/sort.sh
#
# A portable utility that provides a function that sorts an array of a
# specific type.  The sorted output can be in the form of values or
# indices.
#
# This methods were based from QuickSort (the one described in
# "A Book on C 4th Ed.").
#
# Credits have got to be given to the authors of the book
# "A Book on C 4th Ed." for this great algorithm.  The algorithm was
# originally described by someone and was completely explained in the
# book with an implementation that's written in C.
#
# I knew C from many sources but most of what I learned came from this
# book and I therefore recommend it to starters for a good start and
# also to experienced programmers for a good reference and new methods
# that they may discover from it.
#
# I hope you enjoy using these functions and/or algorithms.
#
# Author: konsolebox
# Copyright free, 2008-2013

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------


# array_sort
# (
#   ["from=<array>"],
#   ["type=<string|integer>"],
#   ["to=<array>"],
#   ["as=<values|indices>"],
#   ["--" [ SOURCEVALUES[@] ]]
# )
#
function array_sort {
    [[ $# -eq 0 ]] && return

    local __FROM __TYPE __TO __AS
    local -a __ARRAY
    local -a -i __INDICES

    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
        case "$1" in
        from=*)
            __FROM=${1#from=}
            ;;
        type=*)
            __TYPE=${1#type=}
            ;;
        to=*)
            __TO=${1#to=}
            ;;
        as=*)
            __AS=${1#as=}
            ;;
        --)
            shift
            break
            ;;
        #beginsyntaxcheckblock
        *)
            array_sort_error "unknown parameter: $1"
            ;;
        #endsyntaxcheckblock
        esac
        shift
    done

    #beginsyntaxcheckblock
    [[ -n $__FROM && $__FROM != [[:alpha:]_]*([[:alpha:][:digit:]_]) ]] && \
        array_sort_error "variable name not valid for the source array: $__FROM"
    [[ -n $__TYPE && $__TYPE != @(string|integer) ]] && \
        array_sort_error "argument is not valid for type: $__TYPE"
    [[ -n $__TO && $__TO != [[:alpha:]_]*([[:alpha:][:digit:]_]) ]] && \
        array_sort_error "variable name not valid for the target array: $__TO"
    [[ -n $__AS && $__AS != @(values|indices) ]] && \
        array_sort_error "argument is not valid for as: $__AS"
    [[ -z $__FROM && $# -eq 0 ]] && \
        array_sort_error "a source should be specified either by 'from=<array>' or '-- CONTENTS[@]'"
    #endsyntaxcheckblock

    if [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; then
        __ARRAY=("$@")
    elif [[ -n $__FROM ]]; then
        array_copy "$__FROM" __ARRAY || \
            array_sort_error "failed to make a temporary working copy of $__FROM."
    fi

    [[ -z $__TYPE ]] && __TYPE=string
    [[ -z $__TO ]] && __TO=__
    [[ -z $__AS ]] && __AS=values

    __INDICES=("${!__ARRAY[@]}")

    if [[ ${#__INDICES[@]} -gt 1 ]]; then
        case "$__TYPE" in
        string)
            array_sort_strings 0 "$(( ${#__INDICES[@]} - 1 ))"
            ;;
        integer)
            array_sort_integers 0 "$(( ${#__INDICES[@]} - 1 ))"
            ;;
        esac
    fi

    case "$__AS" in
    values)
        local -i I J=0
        array_reset "$__TO"
        eval "for I in \"\${__INDICES[@]}\"; do ${__TO}[J++]=\${__ARRAY[I]}; done"
        ;;
    indices)
        eval "$__TO=(\"\${__INDICES[@]}\")"
        ;;
    esac
}


# array_sort_strings (uint LEFT, uint RIGHT)
#
function array_sort_strings {
    [[ $1 -lt $2 ]] || return

    local -i LEFT=$1 RIGHT=$2 PIVOT PARTITION

    if array_sort_strings_findpivot; then
        array_sort_strings_partition
        array_sort_strings "$LEFT" "$(( PARTITION - 1 ))"
        array_sort_strings "$PARTITION" "$RIGHT"
    fi
}


# array_sort_strings_findpivot () :: boolean
#
function array_sort_strings_findpivot {
    local -i A B C P MIDDLE

    (( MIDDLE = LEFT + (RIGHT - LEFT) / 2 ))

    (( A = __INDICES[LEFT] ))
    (( B = __INDICES[MIDDLE] ))
    (( C = __INDICES[RIGHT] ))

    [[ ${__ARRAY[A]} > "${__ARRAY[B]}" ]] && (( A = $B, B = $A ))
    [[ ${__ARRAY[A]} > "${__ARRAY[C]}" ]] && (( A = $C, C = $A ))
    [[ ${__ARRAY[B]} > "${__ARRAY[C]}" ]] && (( B = $C, C = $B ))

    if [[ ${__ARRAY[A]} < "${__ARRAY[B]}" ]]; then
        PIVOT=$B
        return 0
    fi

    if [[ ${__ARRAY[B]} < "${__ARRAY[C]}" ]]; then
        PIVOT=$C
        return 0
    fi

    for (( P = LEFT + 1; P < MIDDLE; ++P )); do
        if [[ ${__ARRAY[P]} > "${__ARRAY[A]}" ]]; then
            PIVOT=$P
            return 0
        fi

        if [[ ${__ARRAY[P]} < "${__ARRAY[A]}" ]]; then
            PIVOT=$A
            return 0
        fi
    done

    for (( P = MIDDLE + 1; P < RIGHT; ++P )); do
        if [[ ${__ARRAY[P]} > "${__ARRAY[A]}" ]]; then
            PIVOT=$P
            return 0
        fi

        if [[ ${__ARRAY[P]} < "${__ARRAY[A]}" ]]; then
            PIVOT=$A
            return 0
        fi
    done

    return 1
}


# array_sort_strings_partition ()
#
function array_sort_strings_partition {
    local -i L R T
    local P=${__ARRAY[PIVOT]}

    for (( L = LEFT, R = RIGHT; L <= R; )); do
        while [[ ${__ARRAY[__INDICES[L]]} < "$P" ]]; do
            (( ++L ))
        done

        until [[ ${__ARRAY[__INDICES[R]]} < "$P" ]]; do
            (( --R ))
        done

        [[ L -lt R ]] && (( T = __INDICES[L], __INDICES[L] = __INDICES[R], __INDICES[R] = T, ++L, --R ))
    done

    (( PARTITION = L ))
}


# array_sort_integers (uint LEFT, uint RIGHT)
#
function array_sort_integers {
    [[ $1 -lt $2 ]] || return

    local -i LEFT=$1 RIGHT=$2 PIVOT PARTITION

    if array_sort_integers_findpivot; then
        array_sort_integers_partition
        array_sort_integers "$LEFT" "$(( PARTITION - 1 ))"
        array_sort_integers "$PARTITION" "$RIGHT"
    fi
}


# array_sort_integers_findpivot () :: boolean
#
function array_sort_integers_findpivot {
    local -i A B C P MIDDLE

    (( MIDDLE = LEFT + (RIGHT - LEFT) / 2 ))

    (( A = __INDICES[LEFT] ))
    (( B = __INDICES[MIDDLE] ))
    (( C = __INDICES[RIGHT] ))

    [[ __ARRAY[A] -gt __ARRAY[B] ]] && (( A = $B, B = $A ))
    [[ __ARRAY[A] -gt __ARRAY[C] ]] && (( A = $C, C = $A ))
    [[ __ARRAY[B] -gt __ARRAY[C] ]] && (( B = $C, C = $B ))

    if [[ __ARRAY[A] -lt __ARRAY[B] ]]; then
        PIVOT=$B
        return 0
    fi

    if [[ __ARRAY[B] -lt __ARRAY[C] ]]; then
        PIVOT=$C
        return 0
    fi

    for (( P = LEFT + 1; P < MIDDLE; ++P )); do
        if [[ __ARRAY[P] -gt __ARRAY[A] ]]; then
            PIVOT=$P
            return 0
        fi

        if [[ __ARRAY[P] -lt __ARRAY[A] ]]; then
            PIVOT=$A
            return 0
        fi
    done

    for (( P = MIDDLE + 1; P < RIGHT; ++P )); do
        if [[ __ARRAY[P] -gt __ARRAY[A] ]]; then
            PIVOT=$P
            return 0
        fi

        if [[ __ARRAY[P] -lt __ARRAY[A] ]]; then
            PIVOT=$A
            return 0
        fi
    done

    return 1
}


# array_sort_integers_partition ()
#
function array_sort_integers_partition {
    local -i L R T P

    for (( L = LEFT, R = RIGHT, P = __ARRAY[PIVOT]; L <= R; )); do
        for (( ; __ARRAY[__INDICES[L]] < P; ++L )); do
            continue
        done

        for (( ; __ARRAY[__INDICES[R]] >= P; --R )); do
            continue
        done

        [[ L -lt R ]] && (( T = __INDICES[L], __INDICES[L] = __INDICES[R], __INDICES[R] = T, ++L, --R ))
    done

    (( PARTITION = L ))
}


# array_sort_error (string <message>)
#
function array_sort_error {
    echo "array_sort: $1"
    exit 1
}


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Footnotes:
#
# * In some versions of bash, conditional statements does not properly
#   parse the second string operand so sometimes this form doesn't work:
#
#   [[ $STRINGVAR1 < $STRINGVAR2 ]]
#
#   So to make it work, we have no choice but put it around quotes:
#
#   [[ $STRINGVAR1 < "$STRINGVAR2" ]]
#
# * In some versions of bash, a segmentation fault occurs when
#   assignment statements where sources are arrays are compounded.
#
#   (( A = __A0[INDEX1], B = __A0[INDEX2] ))

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are all the `eval`s you're using necessary? (they do look rather dangerous to me—I hope you're not using this on user input).

Comment: It's on scripting level so it's all about care for the scripter. Surely it would go wrong if he doesn't know  how to make sure that he does pass the parameter's name to the function `array_sort` properly. And yes it is necessary if you want to have a generic function that accepts parameter names as arguments.

Comment: You can't use indirect expansion when assigning a value to it - only when getting its values.

Comment: To assign you can use `printf` (field by field, as in my answer). Arguably not as efficient, but 100% safe with all types of data.

Comment: I've been wanting to make a reply about `printf` actually but you already made a quick reply before I finished it. `printf` and possibly other commands to be used as a general tool for it like `setvalue` (that which I suggested but was ignored) can be used as an alternative to eval, but still it's nothing different if the scripter does not make sure (like sanitizing when needed) that the parameter he/she passes is valid since the script would still not work the way he/she wants it. array_sort was also made (2008) to target Bash 3.0 as minimum. If memory servers correct, `printf` can

Comment: assign values to arrays with indices starting 3.1.